# navbar disappears but no dropdown

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So been trying to set up a navbar that collapses to a drop down when the size is under a certain number of pixels. So far I have managed to make the normal menu disappear when it goes under a certain size, but once I make the window smaller and I have a icon to click (`<a class="navbar-toggle">`) nothing happens, well, if I look at the console, I get a "Clicked Link" on the console from chrome-extension dom.js but no drop down menu. Any idea what I am missing?

This is the menu (in ejs)

```
    <div class="jumbotron cm_header">
        <H1>Construct Mind - Internal</H1>
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
        <div id="slidemenu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li <%if (title == "Home") { %> class="cmh_active"<% } %>><a href="/internal">Home</a></li>
                <li <%if (title == "Whiteboard") { %> class="cmh_active"<% } %>><a href="/internal/whiteboard">Whiteboard</a></li>
                <li <%if (title == "Profile") { %> class="cmh_active"<% } %>><a href="/internal/profile"><%if (user.updateMe) { %><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" ><% } %>Profile<%if (user.updateMe) { %></i><% } %></a></li>
                <li <%if (title == "Addressbook") { %> class="cmh_active"<% } %>><a href="/internal/addressbook">Addressbook</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right login_move">
                <li><a href="/logout"><i class="fa fa-user">&nbsp; Logout</i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>


    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS is loaded, and the following javascript libraries are loaded:

```
<link href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

... code ...


<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/ngDialog/js/ngDialog.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/cmInternal.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is built into bootstrap already. Viewing the html for [bootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/) I see their button looks like this:

```
<button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar" aria-controls="bs-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
```

with the button they have **data-target="#bs-navbar"**.
"#bs-navbar" refers to the ID on their "nav" element

```
<nav id="bs-navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>
      <a href="../getting-started/">Getting started</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="../css/">CSS</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="../components/">Components</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="../javascript/">JavaScript</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="../customize/">Customize</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="http://expo.getbootstrap.com" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Navbar', 'Community links', 'Expo');">Expo</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://blog.getbootstrap.com" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Navbar', 'Community links', 'Blog');">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

You just need to use that combination in your situation to get it to work.

Comment: I never did figure out why the first one did not work, so ended up rebuilding the whole menu using tlindell's answer. It works, looks a bit different as well, but hey, thats all fine :)